# Accessing user time returned from system.time

Tags: r

The output of the following line of code:

```
a <- system.time(sum_lgamma(500)) 
a
```

is

```
user  system elapsed 
  0       0       0
```

How do I access `user` from variable `a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the name with brackets. Here's an example.

```
 a <- system.time(rnorm(50000)) 

    user  system elapsed 
  0.003   0.000   0.004 

names(a)
[1] "user.self"  "sys.self"   "elapsed"    "user.child" "sys.child" 


a["user.self"]
user.self 
0.003
```

Comment: What type is `a`?

Comment: It's of class `proc_time` and is a named vector. See the output from `str(a)`.

Comment: I really get confused on types here. Each type looks similar but different ways of accessing data